# An example of an ideal needed.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb{C}[X]$ be an ideal. I am looking for an example of $A$ such that $A\subsetneq I(Z(A))$.

Here $Z(A)$ is the set of zeroes that are satisfied by all polynomials in $A$ and $I(Z(A))$ is the ideal such that all polynomials contained in it satisfy $Z(A)$.

Comment: Hint: $A$ should not be radical. What is the simplest non-radical ideal in $\mathbf C[X]$?

Comment: Example: $(x+1)^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's a fine example, although $\langle X^2 \rangle$ seems simpler to me.

Answer (score 1):

Take any prime ideal $P \subset \mathbb{C}[X]$ and $A := P^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the ideal of all polynomials that have a zero of multiplicity *greater than 1* at some specific place, for example at 0.

Observe  that it is then quite intuitive that the information about the multiplicty is lost by doing I(Z(A)), so that you get a different ideal then.